# mongodb 3.2 cluster database compatibility to mongodb 5.0

Tags: database, mongodb

We have a mongodb 3.2 production cluster that we need to upgrade to mongodb 5.0.

Instead of upgrading in place, we are considering creating a new mongodb 5.0 cluster, export the DB from 3.2, and import the DB into the mongodb 5.0 cluster.

Will there be any issues with upgrading this way? What we are uncertain about is whether the database format has changed from version 3.2 to 5.0, and whether the database format conversion is only done during the upgrades from 3.2 -> 3.4 -> 3.6 -> ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have backups available just in case something breaks.

Start by reading each major version's Release Notes (to be found here for v4.0 and earlier: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/release-notes/).

Talk to your developers if they use features that might get removed during the version steps, see "Changes Affecting Compatibility".

Upgrading *using dump and restor*e is quite usefully explained here, including caveats: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-upgrade-from-v3-6-3-to-v4-4-5/102366

Upgrading your MongoDB *inplace* is explained in each Release Notes document, for example in https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/release-notes/3.4/#upgrade-procedures (since you mentioned you're using 3.2, 3.4 is the next step to go to).

Repeat.

Again: Have backups available just in case something breaks.